# Cannot seem to delete an object: Django

Tags: html, django, checkbox, view

I have a list of items. Each item has a checkbox. I want to be able to delete an item using a button that deletes all check item (ones that are ticked). I have some jscript which does half of the work, but removing the item from my database is proving a lot of problems. When I press the the delete button, it removes the item. But when I open up the form again, the item returns again.

Here is my view.

```
def edit_order(request, order_no):
#some code
items = models.StorageItem.objects.filter(orderservicelist__order__pk = order.pk)
#some more code including if POST
    item = models.StorageItem.objects.get(pk = id)
        if request.POST.get('delete'):
            item.delete()
```

And my template

```
{% extends "base_popup.html" %}


    {% block title %}
            {{title}}
    {% endblock %}

    {% block script %}

    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{MEDIA_URL}}ui/ui.datepicker.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
                    $("#id_required_date").datepicker({dateFormat:"dd/mm/yy"});
                    $(":checkbox").css("width","auto");
            });
            $(function(){
                    $("#check_all").click(function(){
                            if(this.checked ==true)
                                            $("tbody :checkbox").each(function(){
                                                    this.checked=true;
                                            });
                                    else
                                            $("tbody :checkbox").each(function(){
                                                    this.checked=false;
                                            });
                    });
                       });
    </script>
    <script>
    function hideCheckedRows() {
        var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName("item");
        var checkboxes_to_remove = new Array();
        var count = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
            if (checkboxes[i].checked == true) {
                checkboxes_to_remove[count++] = checkboxes[i];
            }
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes_to_remove.length; i++) {
            cbx = checkboxes_to_remove[i];
            // parentNode.parentNode.parentNode is the <tr>
            // parentNode.parentNode is the <td> containing the checkbox
            cbx.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(cbx.parentNode.parentNode);
        }
    }
    </script>


    {% endblock %}
    {% block content %}
                    <div id="location_header">{{title}}</div>
    <div id="form_container">
    <form action="." method="post">
            <fieldset class="model">

                    <p>
                            <span style="font-weight:bold;font-size:14px">Contact : {{order.contact}}</span>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                            <span style="font-weight:bold;font-size:14px">Cost : {{order.cost}}</span>
                    </p>
                    {{ form.as_p }}
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset class="model">
                    <legend>Items</legend>
                    <table id="items_table">

                            <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                            <td><input type="checkbox" id="check_all" checked="checked"></td>
                                            <td>Tiptop no</td><td>Client no</td><td>Title</td><td>Item type</td>
                                            <td>Format</td>
                                    </tr>
                           </thead>
                            <tbody>
                    {% for item in items %}
                            <tr>
                            <td><input type="checkbox" name="item" value="{{item.pk}}" checked="checked"></td>
                            <td>{{item.tiptop_id}}</td><td>{{item.alternative_id}}</td><td>{{item.title}}</td>
                            <td>{{item.type}}</td><td>{{item.format}}</td>

                            </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                    </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <p>
                            <form method="post" action="help">
                            <table width="60%">
                                    <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                    <select name="contact_id">
                                                    {% for contact in order.contact.client.contact_set.all %}
                                                            <option value="{{contact.pk}}">{{contact}}</option>
                                                    {% endfor %}
                                                    </select>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                   <select name="status_id">
                                                    {% for status in status_list %}
                                                            <option value="{{status.pk}}">{{status}}</option>
                                                    {% endfor %}
                                                    </select>
                                            </td>
                                            <td><input type="submit" name="save_status" value="set status for selected items"></td>
                                    </tr>
                            </table>
                    </form>
                    </p>
            </fieldset>

            <div id="form_footer">
                    <span style="font-size:10px;font-weight:bold;margin-right:10px">
                    </span>
                    <input type="button"  value="Add item" onclick="window.location.href='{% url tiptop.views.client_items name.pk %}'" />
                    <input type="submit" name="save_item" value="Save" onclick="validate_item(this.form)">
                    <input type="button" name="delete" value="Delete Items" onclick="hideCheckedRows()">
            </div>
    </form>
    </div>
    {% endblock %}
```

Comment: How does the view get invoked?

Comment: Oh hold up, let me edit my template. Updated. There is a list of items. Which displays their details.

Comment: I still don't see anything that would invoke the view.

Comment: What do you mean by invoke the view? Sorry my english

Comment: Does the form ever submit anything that actually causes the view to be called and the rows deleted?

Comment: Actually I upload my full views for this edit_order form instead so you can take a look :) UPDATED

Comment: It's the full template you should be showing.

Comment: Ok, I'll show you this. UPDATED

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `request.POST` never contains the `delete` key.

Those `type="button"` elements need to be `type="submit"` to submit the form.

You're just hiding the elements with `hideCheckedRows()`

Comment: @yuji When you mean by request.POST never contains the delete key, are you saying that the input name="delete" should be inside <form action="." method="post"> </form>?

Comment: No, I mean `<input type="button" name="delete" />` should be `<input type="submit" name="delete" />`. `input type="button"` will not appear in your post

Comment: If I do the changes you have just said, hideCheckedRows() no longer hides the checked element. Deleting is also still not working when using the input type "submit" as well. Not sure why it still does not at least delete.

Comment: If you are using `<input type="submit" name="delete"/>` (and clicking on it) AND it's not working, your request.POST.get('delete') line is not even getting a chance to work. In your previous post, you had a bunch of conditions that were not being met, did you remove those and replace it with the simple condition of : `if request.POST.get('delete')`?

Comment: @yuji should I put if request.POST.get('delete') before if request.method == 'POST': or after this statement?

Comment: Solved: Just put the if request.POST.get('delete')  before if request.method == 'POST':. So this seems to work now. Thanks Yuji.